# Microsoft SQL Server table with > 10 million records

Tags: sql-server

i have a master table and corresponding configuration table. Each record in master table can have more than 100 000 records. Master table can have more than 200 records. Which of the following approach is best?

1. Having separate configuration for each master record
2. Having single configuration table for all master records with proper indexing and partitioning

Comment: Partitioning by MasterId will not improve performance if MasterId is already the first column of the clustered index and the column is specified in WHERE clauses. Partitioning can help manageability but will not improve performance if you have proper indexes.

Comment: Without knowing what your tables represent and how they are used, it is impossible to make suggestions. And unfortunately, "best" for you may not be "best" for someone else. You need to define your goal in measurable terms.

Comment: Do you think having separate configuration table for each master record would be better idea sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a single configuration table for all the masters, creating an individual table for each configuration will be very bad.

If you have individual tables for each configuration, you will end up with a lot of issues  like

- Low maintainability
- You might require writing dynamic queries for fetch the data which
  is not good.
- To get the data for multiple configurations, you will be required to
  use UNION, which will impact the performance.
- Any new configuration in the system will lead to code changes.

Fetching data from 100000*200 rows should be fine if your table is indexed properly.

For better performance, you can create a partition on the configuration table on MasterId.